# Reading entire contents of file at a given java.no.file.Path into a String

Tags: java, file-system, io

What I'm wanting to do is create a `String readFile(Path filePath, Charset encoding)` method, that returns the entire contents of a given file.

I'm wanting the equivalent of Guava's [`Files.toString(file, encoding)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)), but without calling the `Path.getFile()` method (as [this method only works with the default filesystem provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile--), and in this particular case I'm wanting to write tests that use [JimFS](https://github.com/google/jimfs)).

I've written the following, but I'm wondering if it can be improved:

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import java.nio.file.Files;
⋮
public String readFile(Path path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    Preconditions.checkState(Files.exists(path), "File does not exist: %s", path);
    Preconditions.checkState(Files.isRegularFile(path), "File is not regular file: %s", path);

    return Joiner.on(System.lineSeparator()).join(Files.readAllLines(path, encoding));
}
```

Is there a better way to read the file in (such as without using `Files.readAllLines()` which results in a slightly awkward `List<String>`). I'd previously joined this result together by streaming the lines of the file, and then immediately collecting them with `Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())`, but since the project has a dependency on Guava for other purposes, it seems preferable to use the `Joiner` available.

I'm happy to restrict this to Java 8 and onwards if needed, and as previously mentioned I already have a dependency on Guava, but I'd rather not add too many dependencies if possible.

Comment: You can refer to [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/326390/1743880).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are missing a relatively obvious, although somewhat [memory-inefficient `Files.readAllBytes(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-) .... Consider this:

```
public String readFile(Path path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), encoding);
}
```

In your code you also have two full copies of the file in-memory at one time, so the files can't be huge. The code I suggest also pulls all the data in to memory twice, once as a `byte[]` array, which gets converted to a `String`, and the `byte[]` array is discarded.

There would be a loopy way to solve it by using a `StringBuilder` and a smaller `byte[]` array, or `ByteBuffer`, but, if your files are smallish, I would not worry about the `byte[]` size.

Comment: Yup, that was obvious! And yes, the files are smallish anyway, so I'm not too concerned about storing everything in-memory inefficiently in this case.